# Problems to access SAP GUI on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, abap, sap-gui

I'm brand new SAP Developer, and I'm having some trouble to access SAP from Eclipse.

The connection is ok, I guess. I can log on, access my local objects, but I can not access some transactions, such as se16n or se11.

I've tried to access transaction se11, for exemple, by typing its name on the screen "Open ABAP Development Object".

I'm using Eclipse Version 2019-12 and Abap Development Tools Version 3.6.0.

Did anyone have the same problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the authorizations to access these transaction codes? There should be a corresponding error message at the bottom of the screen. The SAP administrator can give you the authorizations. Please add information about the exact symptoms, it's hard to help with just "I can not access".

Comment: Ok, I got it. I've tried to access transaction se11, for exemplo, by typing its name on the screen "Open ABAP Development Object". The screen opens up but it stays empty, I can not see the objects.

Comment: Depending on how it is configured, you can’t access these transactions directly from eclipse, you will need to install SAP GUI

Comment: `you can’t access these transactions directly from eclipse, you will need to install SAP GUI` Exacto, muchachita! Eduardo is right, if you access usual (on-premise) ABAP system, you **need** installed SAPGui to access SE11. Mandatory

Comment: You said "I can not access some transactions". Do you mean you can run some other transaction codes? Please share a screenshot, that will help.

Comment: @SandraRossi I can't say exactly which version, but in S/4 you can directly edit some dictionary elements on eclipse: tables, structures, domains, etc...

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/20/new-dictionary-structure-editor/ "This feature is only provided as of NW7.5 SP00."